# storing user data in a csv file vs database

Tags: php, mysql, database, file, csv

I am making a site where user can register and make posts using PHP.
Currently I have 2 tables in a db, and lots of csv files. Both of them together hold, username, password etc. and counters, posts, date etc respectively.

**My Question is** If it is a good idea to go with two storage systems. Of course i can store all of it in a database. My main concern is fast read & write capability.

Also note that some data is required frequently, and some is required rarely, if i have to divide the data b/w csv & db, what can be better way?

Comment: It should all be in a database. The benefits are enormous. The drawbacks are few. Your data likely fits in memory, you're not saving any speed by reading and writing CSV files, you're sacrificing it. CSV files are not databases, they're a format to pass around spreadsheet-like information between applications.

Comment: How many CSV files? Irrespective of how many, how would you manage interacting with those (many) files? How would you deal with concurrent read and write on those files. Database, on the other hand is a much better way to store and manage data and yes, definitely faster.

Answer (score 1):

Use only DB, CSV is not for that.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a format to save your data. It does not offer any ACID compliance like a proper database does. Therefore, if you want to write transactions or want to have concurrency control then you should move to DB. Moreover, if you want to have ACID like functionality with CSV then you will have to implement that on your own which means you are "reinventing-the-wheel". Moreover, if you have multiple CSVs then it can be trouble to handle them especially during data migration. But database solves that too because you normally save your data across tables in just 1 DB file. (which would be multiple CSVs present in 1 folder otherwise).